# querySelector element that does not have class in ancestor tree

Tags: javascript, dom, queryselector

Is it possible using querySelector to select an element as long as it does **not** have an ancestor with a specific class.

E.g. Select all elements that do not have a "b" class at any level of their ancestor tree:

```
<div class="a">
  <span class="element">First</span>
</div>
<div class="b">
  <span class="element">Second</span>
  <div class="c">
    <span class="element">Third</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to exclude both the Second and Third elements from my selection because they are both within the "b" class div.

```
document.querySelector(':not(.b) > element');
// returns the First and Third (because Third is not a direct child)
```

```
document.querySelector(':not(.b) element');
// returns the First and Third (because "c" fulfills the :not selection criteria of not being "b")
```

This is obviously a simplified example. Elements may be nested at various different levels. But as long as they have a "b" class somewhere in their ancestor tree they should be excluded from the selection.

Is this even possible with querySelector?

Edit: I am looking for a solution which uses querySelector on it's own, as I am using a library which only allows me to pass a querySelector string and I don't have access to the libraries internal code to perform additional filtering of results. It seems this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should select all spans and filter them based on their parents.

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
let selections = [...elements].filter(element => !element.closest(".b"));
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that there are other JavaScript methods that can achieve this, but I was hoping for a querySelector string that could accomplish the selection on it's own.
The sample code was just a simplified example. My "real" code involves using a 3rd party library that I need to pass a querySelector string to.

Comment: CSS has no parent selector. That's why you can't achieve this the way you want. You want to select some items, and my code gives you them. I don't understand what makes a difference if you select exactly the same items in a different way. I think you should explain that in your question properly.

Comment: Thanks BA. Yes I didn't think it was possible but wasn't sure. Good to know.
It makes a difference in my case because I am using a library which only allows me to pass a querySelector string. I don't have access to the libraries internal code to perform additional filtering of results.
Question edited to explain reason.